# Jquery Slider - Visual Bar Length On Half-Steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

## [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w6o28751/1/)

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 5,
      min: 0,
      step: .5,
      max: 10,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val(ui.value);
        $(".a, .b, .c, .d").width(ui.value + "0%");
      }
    });
    $(".ui-slider-handle").text("<>");
    $( "#amount" ).val( $("#slider-range-min" ).slider("value") );
  });
```

As you can see, the width of the visual bar works perfectly on integers, but starts acting up on half-steps.

I'm still learning the basics of jquery, but I would imagine there's a way for me to set the bar max value to 20, ignore the .5 step, and translate the output as an array like so

Bar Position | Value Displayed
1 | 0.5
2 | 1.0
3 | 1.5
4 | 2.0
...
20| 10

Comment: Sorry Zack, I may not have been specific enough. On the JSfiddle I posted (top of the question) you can find the html. Slide the increment to a value containing ".5" and you'll see that the width of the green bar isn't calculated properly. There are a few different ways to solve the problem, I'm just not fluent enough in jquery yet to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah I deleted my post after I saw JSFIDDLE at the top, can't believe I missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you're calculating the width of your elements is the problem. You're adding 0% to the end.

So a value of 1 = 10%, 2 = 20%, 3 = 30%, etc. However, with your half steps, this pattern breaks. 1.5 = 1.50%, 2.5 = 2.50%, 3.5 = 3.50%, etc.

You need to multiply, not add. Do this:

```
$(".a, .b, .c, .d").width(ui.value * 10 + "%");
```

That will fix your problem. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w6o28751/2/

Comment: Should have paid more attention in math class. Brilliant, thank you !